# Decrypt RSA cipher with private key in decimal format

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, rsa, private-key

I have a weak RSA public key which I cracked. Now I'm in possession of the private key `d` as an integer. I calculated `d` this way (python3):

```
phin = (p-1)*(q-1)

d = gmpy2.invert(e, phin)
```

where p and q are the factors to calculate the modulus N.

How can I use this to decrypt a given encrypted file? When converting `d` to base64 and wrapping

`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`

`-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`

around, I get the error: `Load key "key.txt": invalid format` using the command `ssh-keygen -y -e -f key.txt`

Comment: the decrypt exponent is only part of the private key. But what do mean by "decrypt a file" and what does `ssh-keygen` have to do with decrypting a file?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk A file has content in it that was encrypted using the weak public key. I want to decrypt this content. I got the command from an answer here on stackoverflow. If that command does not make sense please give me a valid one for my purpose.

Comment: How big is this file? RSA is only designed to encrypt small amounts of data, that's why it's typically used as part of something called hybrid encryption. Trying to decrypt something without knowing **all** the details of how it was encrypted is a frustrating exercise.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Its part of a beginner ctf so its probably a string with something like "flag_xxx"

Comment: The RSA encryption was very likely only applied on a small string that is now safed inside that file. I just want to know how I can decrypt that encrypted data chunk. It should not be too hard but I have no idea how I am supposed to do it. Everywhere on the internet are different tutorial which all say different things. I know that this equation is valid: `m = c^d mod N` and I know all the variables except m, the unencrypted message. So how can I get `m`?

Comment: `m = pow(cc, d, n)` Does not yield to anything working. I try to save the number as binary to a file but I only get trash data.

Comment: `m = pow(cc, d, n)` shows you are indeed on the right track. You should edit your question to show your code for this. There are two important pieces missing: how you created `cc` from the bytes in the file and how you convert `m` to bytes again. For a first try, I would use `int.from_bytes()` for the first, and `m.to_bytes()` for the second.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrap a base64-encoded value with `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`, you are telling your whoever uses this value that it is in a particular format. It is not just the number d. You have a couple of formats to use -- if I recall you can use PKCS #1 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447, or PKCS #8.

The easiest way to get your PKCS 1 formatted, for example, is to use some cryptographic library which lets you give the key in XML, for example, and ask it to produce the base64-encoded DER or PEM value. For example, in C# you have RSA.FromXmlString(String). Build the XML with the appropriate values, which includes your d, and have the library function build the RSA key, and then ask it to give you the PEM format of that key. This will give you the file with `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`, for example, which you can then take the next step and use to decrypt whatever you have.